# CSS - frosted glass effect on hover

Tags: html, css, hover

I have a section in a website where I have two rows of images each with a heading in the centre. My client wants a hover effect with some text showing when you hover over each image. 
At the moment I have the background color on hover set to black. How do I create a frosted glass effect or, at least, how do I make the background a little more transparent so you can still make out the image underneath when you hover?

Here's my code so far (I've just included one image example for the purposes of this) -

```css
#whatwedo {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto; 

}


#whatwedo .container-fluid {

  width: auto;
  margin-left: 100px ;
  margin-right: 100px ;
  border-right: 0 ;
  }
  
.no-gutters {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;

  > .col,
  > [class*="col-"] {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
  }
}

#whatwedo .col {
  /* width: calc(25% - 2rem); */
  /* margin: 1rem; */
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid white;
  /* margin: 30px 0 30px 0; */
}

#whatwedo img {

 
}


#whatwedo h2 {

  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 45%;
  margin: 0 20px 0 20px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
  
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .7s ease;
  background-color: #000;
}

.col:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 4;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="cols">
          <div class="row no-gutters">
            <div class="col">
                    <h2>ADVERTISING</h2>
                    <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/mrmw1974/image/upload/v1506013647/what_we_do1_tfckgo.jpg" class="image" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
                    <div class="overlay">
                     <div class="text"> Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias cum repellat velit quae suscipit c.</br> Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias cum repellat velit quae suscipit c.</br> Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias cum repellat velit quae suscipit c.</div>
                    </div> 
               </div> 
              </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried using rgba? You can use it as a backgroundcolor with an opacity value, where the last value determins the opacity of the color:  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);

Comment: You're setting the opacity to a value of 4, while it only takes values between 0.0 and 1.0, so you probably meant `0.4`?

Comment: @Calaris That would make the text transparent

Comment: @Maharkus Many thanks. Is there any code I can put to make the <h2> heading disappear on hover at the same time?

Comment: Sure, something along the lines of `.col:hover h2 { opacity:0}` should do the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like so :-

```css
#whatwedo {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto; 

}


#whatwedo .container-fluid {

  width: auto;
  margin-left: 100px ;
  margin-right: 100px ;
  border-right: 0 ;
  }
  
.no-gutters {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;

  > .col,
  > [class*="col-"] {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
  }
}

#whatwedo .col {
  /* width: calc(25% - 2rem); */
  /* margin: 1rem; */
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid white;
  /* margin: 30px 0 30px 0; */
}

#whatwedo img {

 
}


#whatwedo h2 {

  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 45%;
  margin: 0 20px 0 20px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
  
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .7s ease;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}

.col:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 4;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="cols">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col">
            <h2>ADVERTISING</h2>
            <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/mrmw1974/image/upload/v1506013647/what_we_do1_tfckgo.jpg" class="image"
                 style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
            <div class="overlay">
                <div class="text"> Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias cum repellat velit
                    quae suscipit c.</br> Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias cum repellat
                    velit quae suscipit c.</br> Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias cum
                    repellat velit quae suscipit c.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change these css classes. you will get transparent overlay.

```
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .7s ease;
  /* Black background with 80% color opacity */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8); 
}

.col:hover .overlay {
  /* opacity maximum value is 1 */
  opacity: 1;
}
```